# Parsing JSON with spaces in key name with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have a json which has spaces in key names.

The JSON has the following format

```
    {
     "response":{"docs":[
        {
          "my name":"krammer",
          "job": "stackexchange"
        }
                }
    }
```

While using ng-repeat to get the parameters into a list, I use the following code

```
{{friends.['my name']}}
```

But this gives an empty output. While

```
friends.my name
```

gives an error.

So how can the key names with empty spaces be accessed using AngularJS ?

Comment: {{friends['my name']}}??

Comment: post your ng-repeat as well plz

Comment: @SajithNair you should have posted it as an answer, because it's obviously the issue.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please try this

```
{{friends['my name']}}
```

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't have anything to do with angular, this is the way we read props from JavaScript object, here you have a object called `friends`. so these are all we can do, if we don't have invalid javascript characters for naming in JavaScript, like space and some other:

```
friends.myname
friends['myname']
friends["myname"]
```

but when we have those invalid characters we only can do:

```
friends['my name']
friends["my name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may run into a case where {{friends['my name']}} does not work. If so, try the following:

```
{{friends.my_name}}
```

Answer (score -1):

`{{friends['my name']}}` will be working fine

Comment: This is exactly the same answer as the accepted one posted two years ago. What extra value does this answer provide?